# Need help refining my excel macro for deleting blank rows or performing another action

Tags: vba, excel

Basically what I'm trying to accomplish is to search the document for blank rows and delete them, if any. This works great if there are blank rows to delete; however, if there are no blank rows, the macro ends with an error. I'd be eternally grateful if someone could advise me how to make this into an "if blank rows then this, if none then that"

```
Sheets ("xml") .Select
Cells.Select
Selection.SpecialCells(x1CellTypeBlanks).Select
Selection.EntireRow.Delete
```

> Enter my second macro (this part works fine)

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me point you to the canonical:

[How to avoid using Select/Activate in Excel VBA macros](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba-macros)

So you can start to understand why your current code fails or performs undesired operation.  What happens when there are no *blank cells* in your selection?  You'll get an error.  Why?

Because in that circumstance, `Selection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks)` evaluates to `Nothing`.  (You can verify this using some debug statements)  And because `Nothing` does not have any properties or methods, you'll get an error, because you're really saying:

`Nothing.Select`

Which is a null program, does not grok, does not compute, etc.

So, you need to test for nothingness with something like this:

```
Sheets("xml").Select
Cells.Select
If Not Selection.SpecialCells(x1CellTypeBlanks) Is Nothing Then 
    Selection.SpecialCells(x1CellTypeBlanks).EntireRow.Delete
End If
```

I still suggest avoiding `Select` at all costs (it is superfluous about 99% of the time and makes for sloppy code which is difficult to debug and maintain).

So you could do something more complete following that line of thought:

```
Dim blankCells as Range  '## Use a range variable.

'## Assign to your variable:
Set blankCells = Sheets("xml").Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks)

'## check for nothingness, delete if needed:
If Not blankCells Is Nothing then blankCells.EntireRow.Delete
```

**Follow-up from comments**

So in VBA we are able to declare *variables* which represent objects or data/values, much like a maths variable in an equation.

A `Range` is a type of object part of the Excel object model, which consists of the Workbook/Worksheets/Cells/Ranges/etc.  (far more than I could hope to convey to you, here)

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff846392(v=office.14).aspx

A good example of why to use variables might be here if you scroll down to the "Why Use Variables" section.

http://www.ozgrid.com/VBA/variables.htm

This is of course very simple... but the reader's digest version is that variables allow us to repeatedly refer to the same object (or value for sipmle data types) without *explicitly* referring to it each time.

THen there is the handy side-effect that the code bcomes more easy to read, maintain and debug, when we use variables instead of absolute references:

```
Dim rng as Range

Set rng = Sheets(1).Range("A1:Q543").Resize(Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(Sheets(1).Range("A:A"),))
```

Imagine that fairly (but not ridiculously) complicated range construct.  If you needed to refer to that range more than once in your code, it would be silly not to assign it to a *variable*, if for no other reason than to save your own sanity from typing (and possibly mistyping a part of it).  It is also easy to maintain, since you need only modify the *one* assignment statement and all subsequent references to `rng` would reflect that change.

Comment: This is helpful and I feel like I'm moving in the right direction. I'm sorry if I sound like an idiot but could you assist me with the range variable? Unfortunately you're speaking to someone who's just being introduced to this part of excel. :c